# Error while building BB webworks application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to use the javascript extension in a blackberry webworks application.I hav the jar file in the ext folder.But whenever i m trying to build the application the error pops up saying :

> 'Missing stack map in: getField at label'.

After searching through sites, it was written somewhere to prevarication process gives error :

> 'JAR file creation failed with error -1'.

Can someone help with the problem stated???

Comment: Means your JAR file has some error; extract it and open with javaDecompilor and see where the error occurs. If it is your own jar file then see where the getField(); gives error;

Comment: currently i am trying to work with the same sample alert example given on blackberry site.

Comment: In config file add the future tag like: <feature id="sample.alert" required="false" version="1.0.0" />

Comment: Earlier it was required="true", evn after changing it to false it is giving the same error

Comment: no need of true or false; problem; You are import the file or copy the JAR file to "ext" folder;

Comment: its already there in the ext folder

Comment: First open a new project and import the project "sampleProject" and debug; did you do like this?

Comment: finally i got that sample alert working...i was keeping all the java files and the library.xml in the same folder..:)

Comment: write your solution as answer and accept your answer;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got that sample alert working...i was keeping all the java files and the library.xml in the same folder..:)